# display data in text box on selection using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple boxes. On selection of anybox I have to display its value in textbox. 
Suppose I select box 1. I have to display value in textbox, and when I unselect the value must disappear. If I select multiple boxes, values must be displayed in text box separated by comma.

How can it be done?

My code is:

```
<input type="text" id="selectedvalue" disabled="true" class="text" name="selectedvalue" />

<tr>
 <td>
      <div class="box A1" id="A1"></div>
 </td>
 <td>
      <div class="box A2"></div>
 </td>
 <td>
      <div class="box A3"></div>
 </td>
 <td>
      <div class="box A4 "></div>
 </td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done using JQuery,

Here is the JavaScript code for that

```
var clickedBoxes=[];

$(".box").on("click", function() {
  var clikedElem = $(this);
  var text='';

  if(clikedElem.hasClass('clicked')){
    clikedElem.removeClass('clicked');
    clickedBoxes.splice(clickedBoxes.indexOf(clikedElem.text()),1);
  }
  else{
    clikedElem.addClass('clicked');
    clickedBoxes.push(clikedElem.text());    
  }
  $('#selectedvalue').val(clickedBoxes);
});
```

Here is a complete [JsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2ahv6dh/)

Comment: Thank you your answer was helpful

Comment: i have a specific box in which if user selects nothing should happen i.e the selected box value should not appear in the text box .how to do so?